# Reason for poor performance of ANSI joins in Oracle 9i

Tags: performance, join, syntax, oracle9i, ansi-sql

**Please before flagging as duplicate, read the last paragraphs.**

In an Oracle 9i database this query runs in **0.18 seconds**:

```
select
    count(*)
from 
    dba_synonyms s,dba_objects t
where
    s.TABLE_OWNER = t.OWNER(+) and
    s.TABLE_NAME = t.OBJECT_NAME(+) and
    s.DB_LINK is null and
    t.OWNER is null;
```

...but this one runs in an appalling **120 seconds**!:

```
select
    count(*)
from 
    dba_synonyms s left join dba_objects t 
                   on ( s.TABLE_OWNER = t.OWNER and s.TABLE_NAME = t.OBJECT_NAME ) 
where                   
    s.DB_LINK is null and
    t.OWNER is null;
```

Notice the only difference is using propietary Oracle join syntax vs ANSI join syntax.

**These question is not a duplicate** of [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75838/drastic-change-in-query-speed-when-changing-from-oracle-9i-to-ansi-outer-join-sy) because that other question is about a very complex query involving more than 9 tables, and the only answer points out that the queries are very different besides the syntax usage (mainly the order of the tables).

In my case it is a extremelly simple query, a mere join between two relations with no mayor complications of differences, including the order of tables.

- **Is this a bug in Oracle 9i?**
- **What is the cause of such dramatic    difference in performance?**

**UPDATE:**

This are the execution plans, *notice that the explain plan for query one shows no cardinality, cost or bytes info* :

**Fast, old-style join:**
[image]
**Slow, ANSI join:**
[image]

Comment: Since Oracle 9i is no longer supported it's very difficult to determine what is causing your performance issues.  Have you tried comparing their explain plans?

Comment: @Sentinel The executions plans are wildly different, but they shouldn't be since in both queries I am just making a simple join. No table order is being changed, no function is being applied on any column, no new conditions were introduced in the WHERE clause, the selected columns are the same, etc. I guess Ora9i just parses the ANSI version in a crazy way, leading to a execution plans which is not only different to the one used for the old-style query, but also a very inefficient one.

Comment: @Sentinel I added the explain plans of each query to the question, please take a look at them. Maybe you can explain to me why the second one is so slow and, most importantly, why Ora9i chose such a bad execution plan over the other one.

Comment: "*Is this a bug in Oracle 9i?*" - I recall that there were loads of issues with the explicit JOIN syntax in Oracle 9 and still some in Oracle 10 (probably one of the reasons acceptance of explicit JOINs in the Oracle community is so low). I have never seen problems with it in 11g or 12c though

Comment: Just tested the queries in 10g and 11g and both versions run in < 1 sec. Problem is 9i only. I even tested in another 9i instance and the ANSI query takes forever (I cancelled it after 7 minutes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after a long time with no answers. I've done some testing.

I ran the same query in 10g and 11g and both versions, the one with ANSI joins and the ones with the WHERE joins run in less than 1 second.

As problems exists only in 9i, the same version the support for ANSI joins where introduced I assume **it's a bug in 9i** that could or could have not be solved in a patch.

Gladly as I mentioned, from 10g onwards both flavors of joins perform well.